# I get an infinite loop only when I render a child component - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, render, infinite-loop

Okay so this is driving me crazy ! Had to restart coding the project from scratch to pinpoint where the problem is.

Basically I'm trying to practice React by building a web app where I can share spotify songs. So here's my Component tree (only the important components: App.js -> [Navbar, Posts] -> then inside Posts i have a list of Post components. Here are the codes:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/Navigation/Navbar';
import Posts from './containers/Posts/Posts';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <Posts />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Post from './Post/Post';
import $ from 'jquery';

class Posts extends Component {
    state = {
        posts: null,
        // addingNewPost: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://music-blog-app.firebaseio.com/users/user/posts.json',
            success: (response) => {
                //console.log(response); // object of objects
                // converting to array of objects
                const responseArray = Object.keys(response).map(i => response[i]);
                //console.log(responseArray);
                this.setState({
                    posts: responseArray
                })
                // console.log(this.state.posts);
            }
            //error
        });
    }

    // addingNewPostHandler = () => {
    //     this.setState({addingNewPost: true});
    // }

    // cancelNewPostHandler = () => {
    //     this.setState({addingNewPost: false});
    // }

    sharedNewPostHandler = (caption, embedSrcLink) => {

        var newPostToAdd = {
            caption: caption,
            embedSrcLink: embedSrcLink
        }

        var postsToUpdate = this.state.posts.slice();
        postsToUpdate.push(newPostToAdd);

        // $.ajax({
        //     type: 'POST',
        //     url: 'https://music-blog-app.firebaseio.com/users/user/posts.json',
        //     success: (response) => {
        //         console.log(response);
        //         this.setState(prevState =>({
        //             addingNewPost: false,
        //             posts: [...this.state.posts, newPostToAdd]
        //         })); 
        //     } 
        //     // error
        // });
    }

    render() {

        var postsToRender = <p>Nothing here</p>

        console.log(this.state.posts);
        if(this.state.posts) {
            var myPosts = this.state.posts.slice();
        }
        console.log(myPosts);
 
        let render;
        if(myPosts) {
            render = (myPosts.map((post, index) => { return <p>IF I REPLACE THIS BY RENDERING POST component, I get an infinite loop</p>}))
        } else {
            render = <p>still waiting...</p>
        }

        return (
            <div className="container posts-container">
                {/* <p>jsdhfjhd</p>
                {myPosts ? (myPosts.map((post, index) => {
                    // console.log(post)
                    return <Post key={post} caption={this.state.posts[index].caption} embedSrcLink={this.state.posts[index].embedSrcLink} />
                })) : <p>still waiting...</p>} */}
                {render}
            </div>
        ); 
    }
}

export default Posts;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Post.css';
import PosterProfile from '../../../components/PosterProfile/PosterProfile';

const post = (props) => (
    <div className="post">
        <PosterProfile />
        <div className="card" style={{width: '18rem'}}>
            <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-caption">{props.caption}</h5>
                <div className="embed-iframe">
                    <iframe title="embed" src={props.embedSrcLink} width="300" height="380" frameBorder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card-footer">
                <a href="#like" className="card-link link">Like</a>
                <a href="#comment" className="card-link link">Comment</a>
                <a href="#repost" className="card-link link">Repost</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)

export default post;
```

**Here is the problem !!** So this piece of code inside the render method of Posts:

```
render = (myPosts.map((post, index) => { return <p>IF I REPLACE THIS BY RENDERING POST component, I get an infinite loop</p>}))
```

**AS SOON AS I replace it with**

```
render = (myPosts.map((post, index) => { 

return <Post key={post} caption={this.state.posts[index].caption} embedSrcLink={this.state.posts[index].embedSrcLink}
}))
```

I am getting the posts from a firebase database by the way.
Please help ! Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you start by removing the `<PosterProfile />` component from the `Post` component to eliminate that as a possibility (just because we don't see the code for that component in your post, and that could be the culprit)

Comment: Could the issue be that you are exporting `post` instead of `Post`

Comment: @jmancherje PosterProfile was just a div with an image. But I removed it and it's still not working

Comment: @AdrianAvram that wasn't it

Comment: @AdrianAvram although it's common practice to name your components with capitals, his variable is `post` and he's exporting `post` so the export is fine. And the import, `import Post from './Post/Post'` is actually an alias so he could have named it anything he wanted

Comment: Ah okay, I still have a lot to learn about react. I will try and recreate error and see if I can find the issue.

Comment: @user10210735 this would not cause an infinite loop, but a `key` in react has to be a unite `string`, and you're passing it an `object`, start by making that a unique string. Do `key={post.embedSrcLink}`.
While you're at it, change the other props as follows: `caption={this.state.posts[index].caption}` => `caption={post.caption}`, because `post` from your `.map` is the post you want already, no need to use the index or your state.
Lastly, remove the `.slice()` in your render `var myPosts = this.state.posts.slice();`, you want to use the actual state in your render, not a copy of it

Comment: okay UPDATE: currently my code is working properly when I render Post. I don't know why this is happening but I will update if something weird happens again.

Comment: @user10210735 did you change the `key` to be a string? I believe that could be the culprit

Comment: @jmancherje alright ! Thank you. I will do that

Comment: @jmancherje currently it's index but I will add ids to my posts later and change it to that

Comment: @user10210735 I'm going to write a quick answer with a description of the fix and react keys

Answer (score 0):

Rendering a list/array in react requires you to add a key to each item. From the docs:
`Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity`
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

I believe what is happening in your snippets, is that you're assigning a key as an object instead of a string. This would definitely cause unexpected behavior or errors.

Comment: Alright thanks. Initially I was going to use key={post.embedSrcLink} as you had suggested but I thought it might cause trouble if I have the same song twice (with the same src link) in my database. So for now it's index. But I will add and id to every post in a bit.